# A body horror story about "mind over matter"

Tags: story-identification

So I don't remember if it's a story, a novel or what. I don't remember where I read it, but it was in the end of 00's. It sort of has 90's vibe, I thought it could be Crichton or King, but I can't find anything similar by them.

The story is sorta technothriller/body horror thing.

What is the primary plot - I don't remember.

One of the plot features is some environment factor (I don't know if it was rays or viruses or what) that causes people to entertain their favorite pastime more and more, while also physically changing them accordingly.

A gamer boy ended up growing wires out of his body directly into his gaming rig and city electrical grid. A gang of street chavs cranked their violence to eleven, turning into a pack of wolf-like creatures, obsessed only with hunt and murder. A bunch of swingers had an orgy until they turned into a colony blob of replicating cells, yet it was somehow complex enough to emit some kind of hypnotising sound to attract other organisms for consumption - at some point protagonist has to resist this call. And I think the werewolf pack can't and ends up being eaten.

Does that look like anything or did I dream it up?

Comment: This does sound familiar. But I know the first scenario was also part of a, I believe, Dean Koontz book where a boy in a private school had been physically connected to his computer. But the other scenarios sound familiar as well. I'll keep thinking about it and try to see if anything gels in my brain today.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for Dean Koontz's 1989 novel Midnight. The novel's premise involves a scientist performing an illegal experiment by injecting colonies of nano-sized computer chips (the environmental factor) into the residents of a small town. Once inside human bodies, the nano-chips combine into a high-powered computer with the capability of controlling the hosts' physiological processes. This cybernetic infection was meant to improve the human condition by eliminating disease, accelerating healing powers, and removing humanity's psychological restraints - thus allowing the hosts to express their secret desires. This had the unexpected result that the hosts' bodies transformed according to their desires.
All of the plot details that you mention are there: the boy melding with his computer, the people turning into werewolf-creatures, and then melting together into the siren-voiced blob.

[image: Cover of "Midnight" by Dean Koontz. A bird of prey is silhouetted against an orange light, while in the midground residential houses are illuminated against a dark background.]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKAouJB5SXg